# openmp slows down near the end of execution

Tags: openmp

I edited a program to a parallel edition, but met a problem. This program is large and I tried to parallelize it at the outmost layer. This program is written in fortran and the following is the scheme of my code.

```
program main
use omp_lib
implicit none

declare some variables...

call omp_set_num_threads(n)
!$OMP parallel do
!$OMP private(a,b,c,d)
do i=1,5000000
   call sub1(a,b,c)
   b=c+d;c=b+d;...
   call sub2(b,c,d)
   if (logical_expression) cycle
   call sub3()
   call sub4()
enddo

end program
```

There are some conditions that the outmost loop will `cycle`, and these conditions mostly happen when `i`s are small. So when I tried to print out which loop `i` is performing, I finally got that near the end of the execution, the `i` is continuous and large. And if I print out `i` on the screen, I saw that the speed of my program was as slow as a sequential edition near the end of the execution. Is there anyone know why and how to solve this problem?

Comment: It is most likely that your OpenMP defaults to a static schedule in which thread 1 gets the first chunk of `i`s, thread 2 the next chunk, and thread N the last chunk.  If the higher values of `i` are less likely to lead to `cycle` then the higher-numbered threads will have more work to do than the lower-numbered ones.  Investigate the OpenMP `schedule` clause to see how to deal with poor load balancing such as you indicate your problem suffers.